# I am getting error code 1045 in xampp server for osx

Tags: mysql, macos, server, phpmyadmin, xampp

In xampp,  I updated  root password,  and now can't able to access  it...  Error code 1045

And tried to configure  config.inc. File,  it saying no permission to edit it.

Pls help me step by step..  I am not able to find solution,  and I am new to os x.

Comment: Search on google. you will get proper step by step

Comment: SO is not the right place for that question. Your question is not related to programming. I'd suggest getting an OS X tutorial and an XAMPP tutorial from somewhere, or asking operating system related questions on superuser.com.

Comment: It's related  to programming,  can't able to fetch or database from phpmyadmin using mysql